# How to add a typeface for ProgressDialog from assets folder?

Tags: progressdialog, assets, typeface

Given my code below.I want to convert the title "Please wait for the call to be activated" to hindi(font which i have given in assets folder)..

```
public ShakeEventsListener(Context context, OnShakeListener mShakeListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mShakeListener = mShakeListener;
        startTime = 0;
        movecount = 0;
        elapsedTime = 0;

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setTitle(" Please wait for the call to be activated");
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

        complexPreferences = MyApplication.getComplexPreference();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By overrideing the setOnShowListner of the DialogInterface.This interface listner is invoked before the dialog is shown.`

```
((AlertDialog) pDialog).setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {



                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("entered","show listner");

                      final int idAlertTitle=getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier( "alertTitle", "id", "android" );
                      TextView textDialog=(TextView)((AlertDialog)dialog).findViewById(idAlertTitle);

                    textDialog.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/DEVANEW.ttf"));;
                }
            });
```

Reference Link:[How to get the title id of the AlertDialog?](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6360)